# Creating XML Elements without namespace declarations

Tags: c#, xml

I attempting to add a new "PropertyGroup" element to the following XML file

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{00AA7ECA-95A0-0000-0000-AD4D2E056BFE}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>testnS</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>testname</AssemblyName>
    <PluginId>4B84E5C0-EC2B-4C0C-8B8E-3FAEB09F74C6</PluginId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The code I am using is as follows (note there is other logic that has been removed) :

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();

        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode refNode = root.SelectSingleNode("x:Project", ns);

        root.SelectSingleNode("Project", ns);

        XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement("PropertyGroup", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
        newElement.InnerXml = "<value>test</value>";
        root.InsertAfter(newElement, refNode);
        doc.Save(filename);
```

This yields the following new element in the XML document :

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <value xmlns="">test</value>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How do I get rid of the namespace declaration on the  element?

Comment: Do you have to use the InnerXml property here? It would be easier to do it explicitly. (It would be even easier using LINQ to XML, if that's an option.)

Comment: Not sure on the LINQ to XML - LINQ is an unknown for me... :-)

Comment: But I have just found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013165/linq-to-xml-adding-an-element

Comment: Is the namespace in your CreateElement call absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to specify the XML namespace for *all* elements you add to the DOM:

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode refNode = root.SelectSingleNode("x:Project", ns);

XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement(
    "PropertyGroup",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
var value = newElement.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(
    "value",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"));
value.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("test"));

root.InsertAfter(newElement, refNode);
```

If you don't do so for any element (or if you use `InnerXml` like that), that element will get the dreaded empty namespace.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this is happening is that you've defined the default namespace for the document to be "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" by having the namespace definition on the root node:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
```

You then proceed to add an element which is in no namespace (the 'null' namespace) to the document. This *has* to be qualified with

```
xmlns=""
```

because if it wasn't it would mean that the new element was in the previously mentioned Microsoft namespace - which it isn't (or rather - which you haven't asked it to be).

So either:

- you actually want the new element to
  be in the Microsoft namespace - in
  which case you need to say so. The
  easiest way is to use createElement
  and supply the namespace, although
  you can probably state it explicitly
  with an xmlns attribute on your
  InnerXml (which is not a particularly
  nice way of adding nodes).
- You really do want this element in
  the null namespace, in which case you
  are probably better of qualifying all
  the other nodes that are not in the
  null namespace with a namespace
  prefix.

I suspect you want the former.

A quick overview on namespaces can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean/1181936#1181936).

Answer (score 5):

To avoid extra `xmlns=""` attribute in newly created elements you can pass root namespace as an argument:

```
 $child = $doc.CreateElement("value", $doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
 $res = $doc.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($child); # res here to avoid extra output
```

which will result in

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <value></value>
</PropertyGroup>
```