# How to remove an attribute from xml element?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm using spring java to parse an xml.

The xml contains the following element:

```
 <component xmlns="">
      <nonXMLBody classCode="DOCBODY" moodCode="EVN">
         <text mediaType="application/pdf" representation="B64">zzz</text>
      </nonXMLBody>
 </component>
```

I need to remove the attribute `xmlns=""`.

I'm have the following code but the attribute `xmlns=""` is still there.

```
Document dom = null;
try {
                    dom = xmlDocBuilder.parse(inpSource);
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
NodeList nodeComponent = dom.getElementsByTagName("component");
Element element = (Element) nodeComponent.item(0);
element.removeAttribute("xmlns");
```

Comment: "with no luck" is a pretty imprecise description on what happened and why it didnt meet your expectations...

Comment: @GyroGearless I mean that the xml is as it is. `xmlns` attribute is still here.

Comment: `xmlns` is a *very special* attribute used to define the **XML namespace**. The unnamed namespace defined by `xmlns=...` also applies to all the elements nested inside the given element. Are you trying to remove the namespace for *all* the elements in the XML? Do you know what namespaces are in XML? Are you aware of what you're asking?

Comment: @Andreas I have one more `xmlns` in my document. However, I need to remove this specific one only. I'm creating a `cda` patient summary document and the validator does not accept `xmlns` for `component` element not for the nested elements.

Comment: Does the other `xmlns` give a different value, i.e. not the `""` empty string?

Comment: @Andreas Yes. The other one is `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"`.

Comment: That means you need to **rename** the elements (`component`, `nonXMLBody`, and `text`). Oh, too bad, elements cannot be renamed. Well then, you need to remove the elements and re-create them with the correct qualified names, while retaining all other attributes and content. That's a lot of work. Maybe fixing the code that created the XML, to do it right in the first place, should be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Andreas comment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483346/creating-xml-elements-without-namespace-declarations) solution I found my solution.

As I set in the comment above I have another one `xmlns` attribute in the beginning of my xml document which is `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"`.

So, in order to have the same namespace in my new elements while creating them, I'm using the following code:

```
Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
Element componetEl = dom.createElement("component");
componetEl.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:hl7-org:v3"); //this is the solution
root.appendChild(componetEl);
Element nonXMLBodyEl = dom.createElement("nonXMLBody");
nonXMLBodyEl.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:hl7-org:v3"); //this is the solution
...
componetEl.appendChild(nonXMLBodyEl);
Element textEl = dom.createElement("text");
textEl.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:hl7-org:v3"); //this is the solution
nonXMLBodyEl.appendChild(textEl);
```

...

Thus, now my resulted xml is:

```
<component>
      <nonXMLBody classCode="DOCBODY" moodCode="EVN">
         <text mediaType="application/pdf" representation="B64">zzz</text>
      </nonXMLBody>
 </component>
```